# Laravel: route to storage folder

Tags: php, laravel-4

What I'm trying to achieve is to make a route to the storage folder so that I can access it even if it's not under the `public` directory.

For example, user's avatars are located in `app\storage\user\avatars\avatar.jpg` and I would like to make a route so that I can access those images from something like `http://localhost/user/avatars/avatar.jpg`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, i would recommend moving the avatars folder to somewhere more publicly accessible. But as its Laravel, you can achieve whatever you want.

```
Route::get('user/avatars/{filename}', function($filename)
{
    $filePath = storage_path().'/user/avatars/'.$filename;

    if ( ! File::exists($filePath) or ( ! $mimeType = getImageContentType($filePath)))
    {
        return Response::make("File does not exist.", 404);
    }

    $fileContents = File::get($filePath);

    return Response::make($fileContents, 200, array('Content-Type' => $mimeType));
});
```

Then somewhere add this custom helper function:

```
function getImageContentType($file)
{
    $mime = exif_imagetype($file);

    if ($mime === IMAGETYPE_JPEG) 
        $contentType = 'image/jpeg';

    elseif ($mime === IMAGETYPE_GIF)
        $contentType = 'image/gif';

    else if ($mime === IMAGETYPE_PNG)
        $contentType = 'image/png';

    else
        $contentType = false;

    return $contentType;
}
```

It may be worth noting that there are security concerns with the method you are proposing and the solutions.

Comment: Code in answer works, which is fine, but you should do that in a framework like Laravel, which had a lot of code written to solve this kind of problem. A Laravel's `Response::download()` has it all figured out and it uses `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse`, which is pretty huge and secure in terms of code. It also does things this answer is not doing, like setting Content-Disposition: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html.

Comment: @antonio That is not helpful if the resulting image is to be used in-page (like an avatar) and not downloaded.

Answer (score 4):

The best way of doing such thing is to use `Response::download()` to serve files outside your public folder:

Create a router:

```
Route::get('/user/avatars/{avatarName}', 'AvatarServerController@downloadAvatar');
```

And in this could be the controller controller you do

```
class AvatarServerController extends Controller {

    public function downloadAvatar($avatarName)
    {
        $fileName = storage_path()."/user/avatars/$avatarName";

        if (File::exists($fileName))
        {
            return Response::download(fileName);
        }

        return Redirect::route('home')->withMessage('Avatar file not found.');
    }

}
```

But, still giving access to anything else than the public folder may be a serious security risk, that's why Laravel is build this way. But there are some other options:

1) Create a symlink:

```
ln -s /var/www/site/app/storage/user/avatars /var/www/site/public/user/avatars
```

And then use them directly:

```
HTML::image('user/avatar/avatar.jpg', 'User avatar');
```

3) Create a virtual host alias pointing to your `app/storage/user/avatars` directory.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to achieve this is using an alias or rewrite on your web server.

If you are using nginx, add this to your server block:

```
# Rewrite for user avatars
location /user/ {
    root /var/www/laravel/app/storage/user;
}
```

For Apache use 'Alias'

```
Alias /user /var/www/laravel/app/storage/user
```

Doing it this way is faster and better performance, than bootstrapping Laravel for every image request.