# Laravel Route to Image in Storage got "Resource Limit Exceeded" in server (and it runs slow)

Tags: php, storage, laravel-5.1

Basically, i'm inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370771/laravel-route-to-storage-folder) in building image manager feature for my blog in laravel. However, for unknown reason i keep hitting Resource Limit in the production server.

Here's my code:

```
//Migrations
        public function up()
            {
                Schema::create('images', function(Blueprint $table){
                  $table->increments('id');
                  $table->string('name')->unique();
                  $table->string('description')->nullable();
                  $table->string('image_path')->unique();
                  $table->string('mime');
                  // $table->integer('width')->unsigned();
                  // $table->integer('height')->unsigned();
                  $table->integer('filesize')->unsigned();
                  $table->timestamps();
                });
            }
    //Route
        Route::get('images/{path}', [
          'as'   => 'images',
          'uses' => 'Common\ImageController@respond'
          ]);
    //Controller
        protected function respond($name)
            {
              $path         = storage_path('/app/images/') . $name;
              if(!Storage::exists('/images/' . $name))
              {
                //if it did not exists in storage, just throw 404
                return abort(404);
              }
              //assume image_path as unique
              $image_entity = ImageEnt::where('image_path', '=', $name)->first();
              if($image_entity != null)
              {
                if($image_entity->mime != null)
                {
                  //200 = HTTP OK
                  return (new Response(Storage::get('/images/' . $name), 200))->header('Content-type', $image_entity->mime);
                }
              }
              return Response()->download($path);
            }
```

Server specification:

- Shared Hosting
- RAM 512 (max php memory also 512)
- PHP max execution    time 30

Comment: perhaps, symlink proposed by an answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370771/laravel-route-to-storage-folder?lq=1 will do.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your PHP config, images tend to be large in size and the default limit in PHP is 2MB. Try `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');`

Comment: no, it's not resource limit on upload but on loading the image into the front ends. also the upload limit is 128MB it should pose no problem unless the laravel execution too slow.