# laravel5 file header (content-length) submits always correct file size

Tags: php, laravel-5, http-headers

my code at the moment:

```
 return response()->download(storage_path('app/10mb.test'), 'bla.txt',
    ['Content-Length:' => Storage::disk('local')->size('10mb.test')]
    );
```

I've used livehttp headers plugin to check if my return works fine, and the correct amount of file size is submitted (I think so from reading http codes). It's strange, the correct filesize is submitted, but when I edit the filesize to sth incorrect like:

```
 return response()->download(storage_path('app/10mb.test'), 'bla.txt',
    ['Content-Length:' => 'Storage::disk('local')-> '12345']
    );
```

The correct filesize is submitted too, I can't understand why? Any idea?

Comment: because, you're using `->download()` try using `->response($content, $status)->header('Content-Length', ....)` instead.

Comment: no way I can set headers using this method? [http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#file-downloads]

Comment: yes, but looking at the code, deep down, it reach symfony.. notice [this](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Response.php#L266)

Comment: So how would you solve this task? Sorry, but I don't understand your last answer, I thought it would be possible to "attach" headers to the download method...

Comment: sorry, i mean, on [symfony\Component\BinaryFileResponse](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/BinaryFileResponse.php#L172) line, it actually replaces your header. sorry, i got myself while reading the code. to clarify, this code is what being called by `response()->download()`, look at [laravel response factory](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php#L129)

Comment: Ahh now I get it, thanks, but what file type would I need to set in case of I have a binary (.exe file) which the user should download, so browser should display only download button...

Comment: a simple `->download()` should do i think, it (symfony) automatically add `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`. however, i'm did not suggest laravel to serve (big) binary data directly as php overheads - it might slows thing down, like [my experience in a certain server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107486/laravel-route-to-image-in-storage-got-resource-limit-exceeded-in-server-and-i).